# Formatting Modbus requests in ruby

Tags: ruby, modbus

I have a modbus device I am trying to communicate with using an ethernet to RS485 device. I'm not sure whether the device uses modbus ASCII or RTU.

I am trying to format a request to a device with address 1. The command code is 11h. I'm not sure I'm formatting the request properly

Here is the string I am using for ASCII - ":010B000000000C\x0D\x0A"

Here is the hex I'm using for RTU: "\x01\x0B\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0B\xA4"

When I send this command it is echoed back but I'm not getting responses. I've been through the modbus documentation and I think I have the correct byte structure. I'm wondering if I'm encoding it right for ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out my ethernet to RS485 device wasn't capable of the correct timing for modbus. Once I purchased a new unit the ascii strings worked.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the checksum should be written in pure bytes, not in ASCII? I mean, try to send `:010B000000000C0D0A` instead of `:010B000000000C\x0D\x0A`.

Also, you wrote that the command is 11h - for my understanding it is 0x11 (hex), and you are sending 0x0B. Or the command is 11 (dec)?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was trying to send 0x11 not 0x0B as you pointed out. The checksum for the above was 0C and the \x0D\x0A was the carriage return and line feed. Unfortunately this didn't solve the issue.